# Regex to exclude special characters Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex to include: Letters, Digits, and Spaces but I want to exclude special characters like `!'^+%&/()=?_-*£#$`, etc.

I thought I can use `[a-zA-Z]` for Letters, `[0-9]` for Digits and `\S` for Space characters.

**[a-zA-Z0-9\s]**

but the string I am trying to clear might have letters like `é,ü,ğ,i,ç` and so on. 
I do not want these letters to be removed.

Is it possible to write such regex?

Comment: `\S` is anything but spaces. You want `\s` (lowercase) to match spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

- `\p{L}` matches anything that is a Unicode letter a-z and letters like é,ü,ğ,i,ç
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `\s` matches a space, tab, carriage return, new line, vertical tab or form feed character

`[\p{L}\d\s]+` should match one or more character present in the list

Here you can see an example:

- https://regex101.com/r/uQmu7a/1

Comment: I think \p{L} also matches these as well `㙹㙺㙻㙼㙽㙾㙿㚀㚁㚂㚃㚄㚅㚆㚇` even not in Unicode mode, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using non regex way then you can do it using [Apache StringUtils.isAlphanumericSpace(String str)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.5452)

Answer (score 0):

You could go a different way.

Note - these two regex have to be run with the `Unicode character class flag` option.

There are two ways to go

---

- Using *alnum* and staying within the Ascii and Extended-Ascii range.

*Note that this `U+011F ğ LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH BREVE` is outside

the 0 - FF range in the regex below, so that won't get matched.*

`(?:\p{Alnum}(?<=[\x{00}-\x{FF}])|\s)+`

Explained

```
 (?:
      \p{Alnum}                     # Any alpha numeric Unicode
      (?<= [\x{00}-\x{FF}] )        # In the  U+0 - U+0FF codepoint range
   |                              # or,
      \s                            # Whitespace
 )+
```

---

- Or, you can go the Latin classes route, using Latin block's/script and staying within the *alnum* range.

`(?:[\p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_A}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_Additional}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_B}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_C}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_D}\p{Block=Basic_Latin}\p{Script=Latin}](?<=\p{Alnum})|\s)+`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      [\p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_A}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_Additional}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_B}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_C}\p{Block=Latin_Extended_D}\p{Block=Basic_Latin}\p{Script=Latin}]
      (?<= \p{Alnum} )
   |
      \s
 )+
```